# Simulate/Emulate Xbox Controller in C++ or C#

Tags: c#, xbox360, emulation, joystick

I have a cooperative PC game, but the second player need Xbox joystick to play. Well i don't have Xbox Controller i have some other 10 buck piece of shit joystick and the game don't recognize him.
So i tried different programs to emulate any joystick to XBox joystick, but because mine is cheap the program wont recognize it too.

So i want try to create a program which Simulate XBox joystick inputs.

Then i will capture mine joystick clicks and send the Xbox simulated one. I know how to capture mine joystick clicks i have done that already.

The question is simple - How to send XBox360 Controller inputs to my PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're forced to use XBOX Controller, i assume you're using XNA

If that's the case, you could try this Wrapper:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/xnadirectinput/