# Emulate Joystick in Java

Tags: java, emulation, joystick

I want to be able to emulate joystick movements using Java as if an Xbox controller was connected to my computer. I know that you can emulate key presses and mouse button presses using the Robot class, but I can't find any way to emulate any buttons or joysticks from something like an Xbox controller.

Comment: What are you planning to use as the joystick?  Keys on a keyboard?

Comment: Using this [system hook](https://github.com/kristian/system-hook/), I want to emulate a joystick going left when I press the left arrow key, right when I press the right arrow key, etc.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with, though?  The example in the README.md seems pretty straight forward to me.

Comment: I know how to use the system hook, I just don't know how to emulate a joystick moving similar to how you can emulate key presses using the Robot class.

Comment: If this helps, I am trying to do something somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284854/simulate-emulate-xbox-controller-in-c-or-c-sharp) but in Java instead of C++ or C#.